# How to upload folder to EC2 using SCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

The transfer of a file  works perfect.

```
scp -i pemfile.pem testfile ubuntu@ec2-x-xx-xxx-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:
```

But the transfer of a folder does not work.

```
scp -r pemfile.pem testfolder ubuntu@ec2-x-xx-xxx-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:
```

Shows the following message:

```
ubuntu@ec2-x-xx-xxx-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

EDIT: I was missing the -i flag in the command for folder transfer. Solved. Thanks.

Comment: Got nothing to do with folders or EC2 - read up on SCP again

Comment: If you solved the problem, please add your solution as an **Answer** rather than putting the solution in the **Question**. You are allowed to submit your own Answer.

Comment: in the second command you removed -i, so you do not authenticate properly, try -r -i pemfile.pem

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was missing the -i flag in the command for folder transfer.